# не правильно ставятся лайки на новости

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Здраствуйте! столкнулся с проблемой со смещением: не правильно ставятся лайки на новости. Тоесть если я ставлю лайк на первую новость, то он ставиться на вторую...

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
    VKApiPost p;
    VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
    .......

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        p = obj.get(position);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        Linkify.addLinks(holder.textPost, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        holder.textPost.setClickable(true);
        holder.textPost.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        holder.like1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    setLike("post", "...", p.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Лайк поставлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    ///
                }}
        });

        holder.textlikePost.setText("" + p.likes_count);
        holder.textrepostPost.setText("" + p.reposts_count);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        holder.textDatePost.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date(p.date * 1000)));

        VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
        att = p.attachments;

        int i;
        imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>(att.size());
        try {
            for (i = 0; i <= att.size(); i++) {
                vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i);
                imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            holder.mNglContent.setImagesData(imgUrls1);
        }}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_FILL) {

            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        }}


    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textPost, news_name, textDatePost, textrepostPost, textlikePost, autor;
        ImageView repost ;
        CircleImageView news_ava;
        CheckBox like1;
        NineGridImageView mNglContent;

        private NineGridImageViewAdapter<String> mAdapter = new NineGridImageViewAdapter<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void onDisplayImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String s) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(s).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ab_app).into(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            protected ImageView generateImageView(Context context) {
                return super.generateImageView(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullPhoto.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, new ArrayList(list));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

            news_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
            news_ava = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_ava);
            textDatePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

            textlikePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);

            like1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_button);
            textrepostPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
            repost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

            mNglContent = (NineGridImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ngl_images);
            mNglContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    public static String setLike(String type, String owner_id, int item_id ) {
        final String[] res = {""};
        VKRequest request = new VKRequest("likes.add", VKParameters.from("type", type, "owner_id", owner_id, "item_id", item_id));
        request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                    res[0] = jsonObject.getString("likes");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
        });
        return res[0];
    }}
```

obj заполняю так:

```
VKRequest reqWall = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, группа, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100, "text"));
                reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
                reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                        String owner = null;
                        try {
                            owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        posts = new VKPostArray();
                        try {
                            posts.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
```

Comment: а как у Вас  VKPostArray obj заполняется?

Comment: ответ обновил..